# Set retentionPolicy for Google cloud storage bucket through ansible Module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, google-cloud-storage

if we want to set the **retention** value below in **ansible module** '**gcp_storage_bucket**'

```
gsutil mb -l us-east1 --retention 15d gs://hclsw-gcp-kohl-n-cluster-backups-as
```

do we have any option for that.. ?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_storage_bucket_module.html#parameter-lifecycle) for `gcp_storage_bucket` has no mention of retention policy features. The closest functionality available directly is [Object Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle). You should check out the documentation to confirm whether there’s no available functionality that can fulfill your use case.

Otherwise, object Retention Policies also are exposed through the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/using-bucket-lock#set-policy) for Cloud Storage ([endpoint](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/patch)):

```
PATCH https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/bucket
```

There is a built-in Ansible [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/uri_module.html), which could work with the endpoint above and streamline the creation of retention policies for a given bucket.

Comment: Yes as you said.. we dont having retention policy features, lifecycle management is not having what ever the feaure am looking for. So ultimately i've used shell only without ansible module.